# Keyframing curves' bevel_depth

Tags: python, bezier-curves, keyframes

I would like to keyframe the bevel_depth property of hundreds of curves. Therefore, I wanted to use the Python interface like so:

```
for sel in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    sel.keyframe_insert(data_path="bevel_depth",index=-1,frame=60)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and results in the error

```
TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "bevel_depth" not found
```

I can manually keyframe the bevel_depth property by hovering the mouse on the property and pressing "i" but this is not feasible for hundreds of curves. What's the correct data_path for the bevel_depth property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I found my mistake. Sorry for bothering you. It seems I have to keyframe the data of the curve:

```
for sel in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    sel.data.keyframe_insert(data_path="bevel_depth",index=-1,frame=60)
```